# What is Vermivorous The Invincible's weak spot?

Tags: borderlands-2

Yesterday, I spent hours trying to spawn Vermivorous The Invincible. After I finally managed to get it to spawn, it killed me pretty easily. Especially since I was alone. I have the Conference Call and I plan to use it to quickly kill Vermivorous The Invincible by targeting its weak spot.

Thus, I would like to know if it even has a weak spot, if it does, where is it?

Comment: It will be much harder to kill him using the Conference Call after the patch that nerfed the shot-gun/amp damage combo.  You moght be better off using the (double penetrating) Unkempt Harold pistol, and/or the Sandhawk SMG. They still get the amp bonus, and both do substantial damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with all insect-like critters, his weak spot is the massive hindbody. You'll need to either aim past his armored front or maneuver around him.

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but this is much easier to do with help from other players to distract him. Also, if you are fighting him in the Tundra Express, and can manage to lure Vermivorous onto the train tracks, and the train hits him, he is insta-dead. No xp, but he should still drop the items.